# Get url parameters for using in a dynamic filter in django

Tags: python, django

Consider this url:

```
www.anysite.com/get_count/?sex=5&sex=6&city=5&city=7&job=7&job=8......
```

For using in dynamic query in view:

```
model = anyModel.objects.filter(sex=5).filter(sex=6).filter(city=5)....
```

How can I insert url parameters in this query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
model = anyModel.objects
for k,vals in request.GET.lists():
    for v in vals:
        model = model.filter(**{k: v})
```

Or, if you want to change the type of filter, (to, for example, `__contains`), you can replace last line with something like:

```
        model = model.filter(**{"%s__contains" % k: v})
```

Another alternative, if you want to interpret multiple values for a get variable as an `OR`, is to use the `in` comparison:

```
model = anyModel.objects
for k,vals in request.GET.lists():
    model = model.filter(**{"%s__in" % k: vals})
```

Comment: `.items()` should probably be `.lists()`; `.items` gets you one value for each key, not a list of values.

Comment: Change `GET.items()` to `GET.lists()` to make your answer correct.

Comment: yep, good point: didn't know about `.lists()`, I treated GET as it were a dict, while it isn't..

Comment: redshadow, many thanks for your help, I have edited your anwser a bit:for k,vals in request.GET.lists():
        s = "%s__in" % k
        q = "[%s]" % (','.join(vals))  
        model = eval('model.filter(%s__in=%s)'%(k,q)). The ` model = model.filter(**{"%s__in" % k: vals})
` has syntax error

Comment: `eval()` is evil and introduces a big security risk; just use `model = model.filter(**{s : vals})`, where `**` extracts maps the dict to kwargs..

Comment: @TheNone by the way, what's the point of doing that change? The `__in` filter accepts a list, as the list already contained in `k`, from `request.GET`...

Comment: @redShadow, thanks for security tip. I have recieve the error somthing like vals must be string

Answer (score 1):

The URL dispatcher [does not match against GET query parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against), so if you had a URL pattern such as `url(r'^get_count$', view, name='get_count')`, then you simply reverse the URL and append the GET query, such as:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from urllib import urlencode

query = (('sex', 5), ('sex', '6'), ('city', 5), ('city', 7))
url = `%s?%s` % (reverse('get_count'), urlencode(query))
```

You should do this in your view as it gets a bit convoluted to accomplish the same in your templates, unless your going to write static queries, such as:

```
{% url 'get_content' %}?sex=5&sex=6&city=5&city=7
```

If your trying to filter a queryset dynamically by inspecting `request.GET` in your views, then I suggest you have a look at [`django-filter`](https://github.com/alex/django-filter). It takes no time at all to integrate it and it will sanitize and validate the GET query, the importance of which developers often overlook and introduce security holes. Using it is as simple as passing `request.GET` to your defined filter and you get the filtered queryset immediately.

Comment: Cool.. I didn't know about django-filter.. Anyways, sure, my answer is just on how to apply multiple filters, but then you should validate attribute names in some way..